# JavaScript Functions/If statements

Tags: javascript

I don't know what wrong with my code and I've been looking/trying to figure it out for a awhile. Can someone please help me!

```
    var sleepCheck = function(numHours) {
        if (sleepCheck >= 8) {
            return "You're getting plenty of sleep! Maybe even too much!";
        } else {
            return "Get some more shut eye!";
    }
};

sleepCheck(10);
```

Comment: You are trying to compare a function with a number, sleepCheck is the function, I think you meant to use numHours which is the parameter to the function

Comment: I'm doing this on a online course and when I put that in it gives me a error saying this "It looks like sleepCheck() isn't returning "You're getting plenty of sleep! Maybe even too much!" when numHours is 10. Check your if / else syntax and whether you're using the correct comparison operator."

Comment: Did you try changing sleepCheck to numHours?

Comment: Yes of course. That's the error after I change the "sleepCheck" to "numHours".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (sleepCheck >= 8)
```

should be

```
if (numHours >= 8)
```

Comment: I'm doing this on a online course and when I put that in it gives me a error saying this "It looks like sleepCheck() isn't returning "You're getting plenty of sleep! Maybe even too much!" when numHours is 10. Check your if / else syntax and whether you're using the correct comparison operator."

Comment: It turns out that there was an extra space somewhere and the course was a bit grumpy about it and wanted it exactly that way.

Comment: @Wilson : and you still think that was a valid question, worth making loose their time to S.O people ? what a shame.

Comment: @Wilson : come on, just take a step back, this issue has no other interest than for you. Imagine someone else discovering this '''issue''' : he'll learn that on some unknown site you mustn't type extra space in the code... no value. Complaint to your site. This question is pointless for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @GameAlchemist it isn't though? This question is fine because it did solve my question I just complained afterwards by mistake because of some extra spaces...

Comment: @GameAlchemist If I was to remove my previous comment from the kind gentleman that answered the question then it would be a completely fine question. It was the comment afterwards that made things awkward. There was still a problem. It was when I used the user that answered it and fixed the spaces that the code actually worked. Without his help the code wouldn't have worked.